# which characters work with jquery keydown event.which

Tags: javascript, jquery, ascii, keydown

basically if you want to execute a function on "enter", you do the following:

```
$('.cls').keydown(function(event){
    if(event.which == 13){
        //execute function
    }
});
```

my question is what ASCII numbers are supported for this `event.which`?

## what I specifically want:

I want to have it run a function on keydown for the following characters: {};:

the ASCII numbers for those characters are, respectively: 123,125,59,58

but when I replace the 13 for "Enter" with any of those numbers, it will not execute the function on those keydowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ";" sign there are "59" code for Firefox and Opera and "186" code for Safari/Chrome/IE (http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html)
Others:

- "{" - 219
- "}" - 221
- ":" - 186

To manually check and test in various browsers use:

```
<input onkeydown="this.nextSibling.innerHTML = event.keyCode"><b></b>
```

Comment: thanks...is there a way then I could do what I want to make it cross browser?

Comment: Maybe jQuery.browser will help you: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/ (if you can use jQuery) or other solution on pure js: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html Only one symbol needs detection - ":" - so you can make special condition for it like "if( (event.which == 59) && browser == 'opera')... Other ambiguous symbols listed here: http://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events#какими-бывают-скан-коды